What is the realitionship between Saguna Brahman and Maya?
What is the relationship between Saguna Brahman and Maya? And which one is close to the word reality?

Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad says in Chap 4, sloka 10:

मायां तु प्रकृतिं विद्यान्मायिनं च महेश्वरम्‌। तस्यावयवभूतैस्तु
व्याप्तं सर्वमिदं जगत्‌॥ māyāṁ tu prakṛtiṁ vidyānmāyinaṁ ca maheśvaram
| tasyāvayavabhūtaistu vyāptaṁ sarvamidaṁ jagat ||

Meaning, Cit:Śakti is the source of all that comes to be. Māyā is its nature manifesting as Prakṛti. This māyā creates countless illusory realities called Jagat. The sensory aspect of Prakṛti is called Prapancha (creation perceived by the five senses). The Principal Authority over this māyā is Maheśwara, and the Jagat is filled with Jiva (beings) that are parts or aspects of Maheśwara. So īśvara is that aspect of consciousness (Brahman) that is both the authority over māyā and so coexistent with it.
Basic Definitions: Brahmanda = Cosmic Egg, Prapancha = 5 Elemental/sensory Creation, Sristi = That which exists and created, Loka = Dimension, Jagath = Reality (everchanging based on loka).
When Ishvara becomes sakara (takes a form) its usually through an Avatara (Tara = Brilliance, Ava-Tara = the Brilliance that is in reach to us)
Source Link

i don't think the word authority is very good, idk

@blue_ego i wouldnt prefer Abrahamic terminology like Lord, Sayar, God, Saviour, shepherd, Ruler, king.........

@blue_ego   If you read Vivekachudamani. you will see that Maya is eternal as Brahman. So there is no ruler or creator of Maya. The Śakti aspect of Cit gives a being an "individual experience" which is maya. Ishwara is not a creator either. Sristikarta means the one who brings creation to being. The power of Ishvara is to remove that maya. Only Ishwara has the right and power to do that (google Define Authority)

@blue_ego I don't know what you mean? Ishwara = Isha + Swa-Ra.  Isha = Authority and Swa-ra = Self. So Ishwara is self-governing, self-powerful, self-ruling. There is no other entity or phenomenon that helps Ishwara. So we who are not self-governing, need Ishwara to uplift us out of maya. How, that is what Yoga is all about. That is why both Shiva and Krishna are called Yogeshwara.

@blue_ego belief is diff from living reality. So Yoga is the only way, reading books is only good for intellectual satisfaction.

Saguna Brahman is Brahman perceived through the veil of Maya. Maya is said to be Vivarta Vada - Apparent Manifestation and Anirvachaniya - Inexpressible. Swami Nikhilananda writes in his Introduction to his translation of Sankaracharya's Atmabodha (Self Knowledge) pp 49-52:

The word maya was used in the Rig-Veda to denote a kind of magical power. There it is said that Indra, through the help of maya, assumed different forms. In the Upanishads the word acquired a philosophical significance. We read in the Svetasvatara Upanishad: "Know Prakriti, or Nature, to be maya, and the Great Lord to be the Master of maya." Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita: "Verily, this divine maya of Mine, consisting of the three gunas, is hard to overcome. But those who take refuge in Me alone, shall cross over this maya."
Sankara speaks of maya as the Power of the Lord, beginingless, and compounded of the three gunas. Though intangible, it can be inferred from the effect it produces. Sadananda says that maya is "something positive, though intangible, which cannot be described as either being or non-being, and which is antagonistic to Knowledge." (Vedantasara 34) Let us try to understand the meaning of these definitions.
Maya cannot be described as either as being or non-being; that is why maya is said to be indefinable. It it were being, in the true sense, then its effect, the tangible universe, would be perceived at all times. For being can never become non-being; the Real can never become unreal. But one does not behold the universe in samadhi or in communion with Brahman, neither in dreamless sleep. On the other hand, if maya were non-being, a non-existent unreality, like the son of a barren woman, the manifold universe could not be seen. One could not see the world of names and forms as real. Therefore maya is said to be "something positive." The word something here denotes its unsubstantiality or worthlessness, because, apart from Brahman, the world, its effect, is both unsubstantial and worthless. The word positive denotes its capability of producing the visible universe. It also serves the purpose of removing the erroneous notion that maya, or ignorance, is pure negation because it is the absence of Knowledge. Maya is said to be "antagonistic to Knowledge" because both maya and its effect, the material universe, disappear when one attains the Knowledge of Brahman. Brahman and maya cannot co-exist any more than the Absolute and the relative, the One and the many. When one of these perceived, the other is non-existent. They are not even correlatives. That is why the question often asked as to how the Absolute becomes the relative world is illogical and meaningless.
As long as one sees maya or its effects, one may say that it belongs to Brahman, because nothing exists, ultimately, but Brahman. Thus maya has been described by Vedantists as the inexplicable power of the Supreme Lord, Paramesasakti, by which is produced the illusion of creation, preservation, and dissolution of the universe....


'something positive' sounds like a cheap kaleidoscope...

There are some good answers here, but I want to answer it from strictly a technical sense. This answer is based on Tattva Bodha credited to Shri Adi Shankaracharya.
First we need to know, What is Maya?


Depending on Brahman for its existence is MAYA, which is of the nature
of the three gunas: Satva, Rajas and Tamas.


Now Who is Jiva and Who is Ishwara?


The consciousness (Atma) conditioned (Upadhi) by Avidya is called Jiva.

The awareness conditioned by Maya is called Isvara



Here is my simple understanding of these verses, when Brahmnan is  covered by pure Sattva it is called Ishvara, when covered with mixed qualities it is considered Jiva, when covered with Tamas predominant guna it is called matter or Jada.
Here is a detailed explanation of the same verses by Svarupa Chaitanya from Chinmaya mission.

The self identifying with the body is called Jiva. Jiva possesses both
gross and subtle body. The subtle body reflects consciousness.
Insentient objects do not possess subtle body and therefore they do
not reflect consciousness. One subtle body identifies with only one
gross body.
Consciousness is everywhere, just as space is every- where. Space transcends everything that stands in it and therefore moving an
object from one place to another does not need moving of its
corresponding space with it, because space is everywhere. Similarly
consciousness or Atman is everywhere. Wherever the subtle body is, it
is enlivened by consciousness. When the subtle body leaves the gross
body, the latter dies and decays. But the subtle body glows with
consciousness, wherever it goes. This is analogous to a red hot iron
ball, which glows because of the fire. Thus the Jiva is reflection of
Brahman or Consciousness.
Jiva is nothing but Atman (Self) conditioned by the Upadhi (conditioning or limiting adjunct) called Avidya. Isvara, on
the other hand, is the Self (Brahman) conditioned by the Upadhi called
Maya. Thus while the Jiva is conditioned by individual ignorance,
Isvara is conditioned by Maya which is total ignorance. An important
difference between Jiva and Isvara is that Jiva is under the influence
of Maya while Isvara controls or wields Maya.
Both Jiva and Isvara are the same Consciousness with different Upadhis. Therefore, basically they are one. How- ever, due to this
difference in Upadhis which arises out of self-ignorance, the Jiva
considers himself as different from Isvara like an actor who has
forgotton his identity. A wave does not know that it is made up of the
same substance as the ocean and therefore it considers itself to be
different from the ocean. The wave cannot have the vision of the ocean
as long as it excludes itself from the ocean! Just as the wave lives a
transient existence of a few minutes, to be born again as a wave and
die again, the Jiva also experiences a transitory life and suffers the
pangs of Samsara, or the life of repeated births and deaths. The cause
for the difference between Jiva and Isvara is self-ignorance. Man
feels incomplete and always wanting. The only way to redeem oneself
from the effect of separate- ness from Brahman is to remove the cause,
viz. Ignorance. Ignorance is removed by subjective knowledge and by it
alone. The Sruti says: Knowledge alone liberates (Jnanadeva tu
Kaivalyam).


P.S: I think Tattva Bodha, an Advaita Beginner's handbook is an excellent book which explains so many concepts in detail. Anyone who wants to start learning Advaita needs to read this excellent book.

Tattva Bodha, just basic Hindi-English translation.
Tattva Bodha, by Svarupa Chaitanya from Chinmaya mission.
Tattva Bodha, with explanation and graphical representation


i prefer your explanation over number 29

@blue_ego no 29?? you mean verse no 29?? That's the same thing
